# Social network post links not working properly

Tags: facebook, metadata, hyperlink, google-plus

The problem I'm having is when I post a link to a post on my website to either Facebook or Google+ that link points to my homepage. Even in preview, the thumbnail displayed is that of the homepage.

From what I have found (which hasn't been much) it seems that the problem might be with the facebook metadata. I have tried to validate it on facebook's open graph validator and at first I was getting a 206 result when the links were working. Now I get: Facebook URLs aren't scrapable by this Debugger. Try your own. Not sure why.

Having the same issue with Google+. When I first published the website it was working fine and this happened out of nowhere.

Here is what I have in my header:

```
  <!--Facebook Metadata /-->
  <meta property="og:title" content="Website Title"/>
  <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://URL.com/"/>
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://URL.com/img.png"/>
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Site Name"/>
  <meta property="fb:admins" content="User_1"/>
  <meta property="og:description" content="Website Descriptiom"/>

  <!--Google+ Metadata /-->
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Google+ ID">
    <meta itemprop="description" content="Description">
    <meta itemprop="image" content="Empty">
```

I have tried removing it and still the problem persists. I do want to point out that I have an html site with a wordpress blog that's being hosted on my server. Wondering if the issue might be with wordpress?

Should the metadata be placed on the index.html and the wordpress homepage or just the index.html? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. Would it be better for me to keep this question open and edit the old one or to just leave that one as deleted and leave this one open. I don't want to have the same question repeated.

Comment: I don't know what would be best to do at this point. I've already flagged this post for moderator attention explaining the situation. Hopefully they'll see your comment and act accordingly. You could always search and/or ask on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) about what you should do.

Comment: I wasn't referring about the question but about the posts since you keep flagging them. I'm just trying to ask for help like I have a couple times before. I didn't think it would be this big of a hassle.

Comment: The problem I'm referring to is that you asked the question, then deleted it and asked again after the first one got downvoted. (Yes I know it has more detail, but it's still the same question.) This is characteristic of abusive behavior, but hopefully people can see from your comment that you'll learn from this experience.

Comment: I understand your point. My question now is, since you flagged both of my posts how should I proceed to get help with my issue? Or should I just forget about trying to get help on this website altogether?

Comment: For now, I wouldn't worry about it. You've got the comments above to show you'll learn from this, but if you're concerned, you could post on meta. (Click the link at the top of the page.)

Answer (score 0):

When you delete those metadata tags, specifically the og: ones (facebook's open graph meta tags) - you have to tell Facebook to pick up a new copy of your page as they cache everything. If you haven't tried this already:

1. Remove those tags
2. View the source on your live site, to confirm they are in fact removed
3. Go to http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and type in the URL of the page you are testing. This will tell Facebook to grab a new copy.

If that works (as it should), then you can play around with what tags to keep and how to make them dynamic - knowing that anytime you make a change, you will have to redo step #3 to tell FB to grab a fresh copy.

Comment: Thank you Jewel for your reply. I did give this a try but I the following error from the debudder:

"Facebook URLs aren't scrapable by this Debugger. Try your own."

I'm not sure why that would be?

Comment: @Angel that sounds like you were typing a http://facebook.com/... URL into the debug field. Make sure you're entering the URL for your blog, e.g. http://URL.com

Comment: I did type in my url not Facebook's. This issue has me stumped.

Comment: @Angel Perplexing! If you're comfortable sharing your site URL, I'd love to have a look.